# How i can show different image on each div using *ngFor or with something else?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ngfor

This is custom made gallery now i want to use titration on the wrapper to have a diffrent image on each and every div. while my code repeate single image on the whole gallery

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper" *ngFor="let data of collection" >
  <div class="row mt-5 paddingP">
    <div class="col-4 top3images " >
      <img class="top3"
        src={{data.completeIamgepath}}
        alt="">
      <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
      <label class="label">207 Products</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 top3images">
      <img class="top3 " src={{data.completeIamgepath}} alt="">
      <button class="button"> Save </button>
      <label class="label">207 Products</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 top3images">
      <img class="top3 "
      src={{data.completeIamgepath}}
        alt="">
      <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
      <label class="label">207 Products</label>
    </div>
  </div>

 

  <div class="wrapper paddingrightleft  secondrowmargintop ">
    <div class="row paddingR">
      <div class="col-7">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 padding0 ">
            <img class="imgs2ndrow"
            src={{data.completeIamgepath}}
              alt="">
            <button class="button"> Save </button>
            <label class="label">107 Products</label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By a piece of your template, I see you expect pictures from the "collection" to be displayed. Are you sure that you have different pictures in your collection? You can check it simply by displaying in the template {{collection | json}}
If there are really different pictures in the "data.completeIamgepath" field, then try to close the template first, that is, the piece of code you gave as an example is not complete. your div with class "wrapper" is not closed.

Comment: i cant share whole code here that why i take a small piece for just an idea

Comment: Have you tried pulling data from a collecition?